# Chrome Dev Tools: View unminified CSS

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, minify

Perhaps I'm missing something (a toggle perhaps) but is there a way to view the unminified (prettyprint) version of a minified CSS source file in Chrome dev tools?

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is the minified version :

[image]

And here goes the unminified one :

[image]

Comment: which version of chrome it is? I don't have the '{}' button in 41.0.2272.101 m

Comment: @AlexParamonov which tab you are in when trying to find '{}' ?

Comment: that is odd, but I see it now under the "sources" tab.

Comment: @AlexParamonov congratulations :)

Comment: Still relevant in 2017, you sir are my hero.

Answer (score 2):

Under the sources tab, just click on the "{ }" button.