# sourcemappingurl regular minified css

Tags: css, debugging, resources, google-chrome-devtools, minify

**sourceMappingURL** seems great but many use cases and examples I've seen use sass/less, CoffeeScript etc.

Is it possible to simply serve a regular minified CSS file and source map it to the unminified version for debugging?

Thanks

Comment: Why not? Have you tried it and encountered a problem?

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried with the bootstrap css file, it seemed to just show the minified version in the sources tab in chrome dev tools. (I have them enabled in my chrome settings).

Comment: Your question is answered in this. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884783/chrome-dev-tools-view-unminified-css